# complexity for nested loops ratio 1/2

Tags: c, complexity-theory, big-o

I am trying to figure out the complexity of a for loop using Big O notation. I have done this before in my other classes, but this one is more rigorous than the others because it is on the actual algorithm. The code is as follows:

```
for(i=n ; i>1 ; i/=2) //for any size n
{
    for(j = 1; j < i; j++)
    {
      x+=a
    }
}
```

The instruction x+=a is executed for a total of n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + 1 times.

Sum of the first log2n terms of a G.P. with starting term n and common ratio 1/2 is, (n (1-(1/2)log2n))/(1/2). Thus the complexity of the first code fragment is O(n).

correct ?

Comment: This appears to be identical to your previous question. Please don't post duplicate questions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are correct. However, you do not need to involve logarithms for that, because:

```
n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + 1 = 2*n - 1
```

(this equation is exact for n that is power of 2, and slightly off for non-power of 2)

**UPDATE**: Proof.

Let's call our sum `x`:

```
x = n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + 1
```

Also, for simplicity, assume that n is power of 2, so all members are divisible by power of 2 without remainders.

If you multiply `x` by `2`, you will see something very interesting:

```
2*x = 2*n + 2*(n/2) + 2*(n/4) + ... + 2
```

or, you can rewrite this as:

```
2*x = 2*n + x - 1
```

which can be simplified as:

```
x = 2*n - 1
```

Comment: updated answer to add formal proof

Comment: this 2*n - 1 just for first loop ore for all inner and first

Comment: `2*n-1` is how many times line `x+=a` will be executed

Comment: that mean complexity for this question it 2*n-1 = o(n) ?

Comment: Of course. Complexity of `O(2*n)` is considered the same as `O(n)`

Comment: this complexity right for this loops ? inner and nested

Comment: yes, this is exactly how many times body of most inner loop will be executed in total by your program